# Update files on folders and subfolder

Tags: linux

I have these files:

- `/home/user1/file1.txt`
- `/home/user1/file2.txt`
- `/home/user1/file3.txt`
- `/home/user1/file4.txt`
- `/backup/user1/file1.txt`
- `/backup/user1/file3.txt`

I need to send `file2.txt` and `file4.txt` to `/backup/user1/` without touching allready backed-up files.

There is a way to do it on terminal? like a combine or update the folders?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is

```
cp -n /home/user1/* /backup/user1
```

The `-n` option tells `cp` not to overwrite existing files.

Comment: to do this for all users folders on /home/ there is a way?

Comment: i.e. cp -n /home/*/* /backup/ ??